# Updated Qt library; cannot build anymore

Tags: c++, macos, qt, build, cmake

I have a previously working Qt5/cmake project which built fine. I then updated Qt from 5.6 to 5.8. Now cmake cannot find Qt anymore.

This is my `CMakeLists.txt` file:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.0)
project(TEST)
set(CMAKE_INCLUDE_CURRENT_DIR ON)

set(CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH "/opt/Qt/Qt5.8.0")
set(QT_QMAKE_EXECUTABLE ${CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH}/5.8/clang_64/bin/qmake)

find_package(Qt5Widgets)
...
```

This is the error message I get:

```
CMake Warning at CMakeLists.txt:56 (find_package):
  By not providing "FindQt5Widgets.cmake" in CMAKE_MODULE_PATH this project
  has asked CMake to find a package configuration file provided by
  "Qt5Widgets", but CMake did not find one.

  Could not find a package configuration file provided by "Qt5Widgets" with
  any of the following names:

    Qt5WidgetsConfig.cmake
    qt5widgets-config.cmake

  Add the installation prefix of "Qt5Widgets" to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH or set
  "Qt5Widgets_DIR" to a directory containing one of the above files.  If
  "Qt5Widgets" provides a separate development package or SDK, be sure it has
  been installed.
```

I followed what written in [Qt documentation](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/cmake-manual.html), so I do not understand what is wrong.

Version details:
- cmake 3.9.0
- Qt 5.8.0
- QMake 3.1
- Mac OS X 10.9.5

Comment: Have you tried removing `CMakeCache.txt` from your build folder?

Comment: @Dmitry: Yes, no difference.

Comment: Make sure your updated Qt installation can be found by CMake: try to run `cmake -DCMAKE_PREFIX_PATH=/opt/Qt/Qt5.8.0`

Comment: I tried to specify Qt's path both on the command line and in CMakeLists.txt, without success.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed setting the following system variables:

```
QTDIR=/opt/Qt/Qt5.8.0/5.8/clang_64
PATH=$PATH:/opt/Qt/Qt5.8.0/5.8/clang_64/bin
```

and removing:

```
set(CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH "/opt/Qt/Qt5.8.0")
```

from CMakeLists.txt.

Answer (score 0):

Did you check CMake version that is compatible with QT? Also did you check that everything is ok with qmake? Because this is what causes the problems most of the times. Check `QT_QMAKE_EXECUTABLE` to be pointing in the new QT version, i get problems with new versions of QT all the time.

Comment: I am using the almost latest versions of both CMake and Qt. QMake is ok, I manually set the path.